# Does having a PHP closing tag at the end of a file ever have any impact on behavior?

Tags: php

I know that having a PHP closing tag at the end of a PHP only file is considered to be bad practice. I understand why it is considered to be bad practice. I do not use them in my code.

I also understand that you do need to use the closing PHP tag immediately before you start writing non-PHP code in that file if it comes after PHP code.

Here is my question: Is there ever a code behavioral change when you have a closing PHP tag at the end of a PHP file? I find the lack of discussion about this very strange. The manual says that it is preferable not to use a closing PHP tag if a file is pure PHP code.

But what about when it is not pure PHP code? What if you have some PHP and some not PHP, but the very last part of the file is PHP? In that case, would there be any code behavior change by including or excluding the closing PHP tag at the end of the file?

I am not asking about best practice or your thinking on if something is or is not a good idea. I am asking if this changes the behavior of the code.

Here is an example of the case I am describing:

```
<?php
  // some PHP code here
?>
<!-- some HTML here -->
<?php
  // some more PHP code here
  // does this last close actually do anything?
?>
```

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say having the close tag is _bad_ practice, as such. It just makes it easier to avoid sending whitespace to the browser unintentionally, which is why not using them is recommended. That said, in your example, I would leave it in - you've sent HTML and headers to the browser already.

Comment: (I've removed the commentary about voting - these don't belong in questions, and sometimes they irk readers sufficiently that they DV anyway. Probably best avoided!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it won't change anything.

The recommendation stems from people getting `headers already sent` error messages when they `include` PHP files/libraries with an inadvertent space or newline after their final `?>`, then attempt to work with headers/cookies/etc. that no longer work once any output has been sent to the browser.

Since you're sending HTML before the `?>` in question in your example, the recommendation isn't as important in *this specific case*. Skipping it remains a good practice to get in the habit of regardless.